# Set LinearLayout height for variable text android

Tags: android, android-layout

There are my code:

Java code:

```
private void buildGrafica(final String sottotipo, final String text, String note, final int sottotipoID){

        final ViewGroup mContainerView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linear2);

        //infilo la nuova birra attraverso un importazione del layout
        final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.chosen_beer, mContainerView, false);

        //infilo la nuova birra attraverso un importazione del layout
        final ViewGroup newView2 = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.chosen_beer2, mContainerView, false);

        if(sottotipo=="Titolo"){
            // inserisco
            ((TextView) newView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(sottotipo+" : "+text);
            newView.findViewById(R.id.mod_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Deleto la riga
                    // perchè mContainerView è android:animateLayoutChanges settato come true,
                    // questa rimozione è automaticamente animata.
                    mContainerView.removeView(newView);

                    // se non c'è più nessuna riga
                    if (mContainerView.getChildCount() == 0) {
                        findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{

            ((TextView) newView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(sottotipo+" : \n\n");
            newView.findViewById(R.id.mod_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Deleto la riga
                    // perchè mContainerView è android:animateLayoutChanges settato come true,
                    // questa rimozione è automaticamente animata.
                    mContainerView.removeView(newView);

                    // se non c'è più nessuna riga
                    if (mContainerView.getChildCount() == 0) {
                        findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });

            ((TextView) newView2.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(text+" \n\n\nNote:\n"+note);

        }

        mContainerView.addView(newView, 0);
        mContainerView.addView(newView2,0);

    }
```

Activity:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Infilate activity1:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="8dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <!-- A button that, when pressed, will delete this list item row from its container. -->
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/mod_button"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_modifica"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:contentDescription="@string/modify_string" />

    <!-- Dummy text view that will display the name of a random country. -->
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:clickable="true"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Infilate activity2:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:dividerPadding="8dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <!-- Dummy text view that will display the name of a random country. -->
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
        style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="48dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:text=""/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have one big problem, i dont know how print TEXT entirely

`((TextView) newView2.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(text+" \n\n\nNote:\n"+note);`

My layout page should be so.

---

TITLE

IMAGE|TITLE RAW

VARIABLE TEXT very long

IMAGE|TITLE RAW

VARIABLE TEXT very long

IMAGE|TITLE RAW

VARIABLE TEXT very long
......

---------------instead it is--------------------------------------------------

TITLE

IMAGE|TITLE RAW

VARIABLE TEXT height as the image and not visible

IMAGE|TITLE RAW

VARIABLE TEXT height as the image and not visible

IMAGE|TITLE RAW

VARIABLE TEXT height as the image and not visible
......

Someone would know say some method to do what I need?
Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a fixed height for the parent layout, so your `TextView` max height will be limited to the parent height.

Change `android:layout_height="?android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall"`

to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Answer (score 0):

change the height of linearlayout to wrap_content.